# How to make Qt application with no main window and ocassional dialogs?

Tags: qt, dialog

How to implement a Qt application reading from stdin, printing to stdout and stderr, and having no main window. But at some times it would display an interactive dialog in a separate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialogs have to go in the main thread, period.

However, nothing is stopping you from using stdin/stdout in the meantime. Also, if you have concerns with blocking, do the stdio read/write in a separate thread.

Comment: Any reference to documentation?

Comment: Some examples would be enough.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to code up the app for you. I think you're better off learning it yourself, or at least learn to use google to find documentation and examples.